# NSFetchedResultsController do not get updated when the managedobjectcontext change

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I make a program where I sometimes moves some anchor to another

When I move those anchors I would recompute distance of bizs nearby the 2 anchors (before and after anchors). The computation is done in background

I used this standard code to update stuff

```
+(void)commit {
    // get the moc for this thread

    [Tools breakIfLock];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSThread *thread = [NSThread currentThread];

    DLog(@"threadKey commit%@" , [[self class]threadKey]);

    if ([thread isMainThread] == NO) {
        // only observe notifications other than the main thread
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:moc];
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![moc save:&error]) {
        CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);
        DLog(@"What the hell error is it");
    }
    else{

    }

    if ([thread isMainThread] == NO) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:moc];
    }
    //[GrabClass StopNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible];

}

+(void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        BadgerNewAppDelegate *delegate = [BNUtilitiesQuick appDelegate];
        DLog (@"currentThreadinContextDidSave: %@",[self threadKey]); 
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = delegate.managedObjectContext; //delegate for main object
        CLog(@"saveNotification : %@",saveNotification);
        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
    });


    //[moc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

I break point and see that distances did get updated. Everything is fine

However the `NSFetchedResultsController` fetchedObjects doesn't seem to get updated and still use the old value.

How can that be?

Also the

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    DLog(@"controllerWillChangeContent: %@", controller);
    [self.tableViewA beginUpdates];
}
```

is never called even though the `NSManagedObjectContext` has changes.

Well actually I wasn't sure if the `managedObjectContext` has changed or not. How do I know? I mean will change in managedObjectContext ensure changes in `fetchController.fetchedObjects`.

There is no caching as far as I know. How can I be sure of that too?

Comment: Just to check: did you set the NSFetchedResultsController's delegate?

Comment: yes of course. it's often called too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation for `fetchedObjects` property states:

> The results array only includes instances of the entity specified by
>   the fetch request (fetchRequest) and that match its predicate. (If the
>   fetch request has no predicate, then the results array includes all
>   instances of the entity specified by the fetch request.)
>
> The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in
>   the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the
>   persistent store. **The returned array does not, however, update as
>   managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted.**
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.0 and later.

I can't say what the appropriate workaround is.  My first thought is to call `performFetch:` in `controllerDidChangeContent:` in the delegate implementation.

The `fetchedObjects` array appears to update simply by overriding `controllerDidChangeContent:` with an empty implementation.  This is the case using both the iPad and the iPad simulator for iOS 5.1.

There's clearly some discrepancy between the documentation and what I have observed.  I have no explanation.  Sorry.  I can only suggest that you perform the fetch in `controllerDidChangeContent:` just to be safe.

Comment: To address your last question: if cachedName is nil in the following method, your FRC will not cache.  NSFetchedResultsController initWithFetchRequest: managedObjectContext: sectionNameKeyPath: cachedName: